# Check every possible combination of numbers against one

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, combinations

I currently load numbers into an array, these are always different numbers and there can be any amount of them, here is an example;

`Array
(
    [0] => 60.0
    [1] => 56.8
    [2] => 42.08
    [3] => 52.16
    [4] => 52.8
)`

I am trying to calculate every possible out come of this array, I simply need to add all numbers together (apart from the key number and its self) and try to match a figure, for example;

`60.0 + 56.8,
60.0 + 42.08,
60.0 + 52.16`
etc etc

Then to
`56.8 + 60.0, 56.8 + 42.08`
etc etc

but not including;
`60.0 + 60.0` or another calculations that include themselfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one..

```
   $str = Array ( "60.0","56.8","42.08","52.16","52.8" );
$result = array();
foreach ($str as $v){
    foreach($str as $d){
        if($d!=$v){

            $result[]=$v."+".$d;
        }
    }
}

$strResult = implode(",",$result);
print_r($strResult);
```

Comment: I found this answer to be the best fit, thank you very much @shark, I have one question, is it possible to modify this code to take a parameter which controls how many sums it does, it currently adds two values together, but is it possible to say 4 values, which it then calcualtes? Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I can offer the solution via grouping source values to pairs, like this:

```
function array_repeat_pair($rgData)
{
    $rgRepeats  = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($rgData);$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<count($rgData);$j++)
        {
            if($i!=$j && !array_key_exists($i*$i+$j*$j, $rgRepeats))
            {
                $rgRepeats[$i*$i+$j*$j] = [$rgData[$i], $rgData[$j]];
            }
        }
    }
    return $rgRepeats;
}

$rgData   = [60.0, 52.7, 54.2, 45.8];
$rgResult = array_map('array_sum', array_repeat_pair($rgData));
//var_dump($rgResult);
```

Not sure if it is exactly what you need (i.e. pair [a,b] is treated same as [b,a])

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to check it thoroughly at the moment, but I believe this will work:-

```
$array = array(60,56.8,42.08,52.16,52.8);

while(count($array) > 0){
    $first = array_shift($array);
    foreach($array as $value){
        $result[] = $first + $value;
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
array (size=10)
  0 => float 116.8
  1 => float 102.08
  2 => float 112.16
  3 => float 112.8
  4 => float 98.88
  5 => float 108.96
  6 => float 109.6
  7 => float 94.24
  8 => float 94.88
  9 => float 104.96
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/XUKgM)